# How to programmatically keep wifi alive in sleep mode

Tags: iphone

I'm programming download data from my server. My idea: i set time for download, my app is running in background, my device on battery charging. When my device is sleeping, if schedule on time, app download data. But, wifi sleep when device sleep. How to re-active or keep wifi alive.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the [UIRequiresPersistentWiFi](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) key in your Info.plist.

Comment: I'm trying your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your app is in the background, you can't run in the background automatically. You will need the user's approval to download the new content. It will have to come out of sleep for such a thing to occur.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, there are solution for me. My application's using: UILocalNotification, NSRunloop. When my application download data, it must have condition: running background, set schedule for download, battery charging, download data, alert message success download, entry application

Comment: Local Notifications will alert the user and if the user is interested, then only will your app be able to act on it or else no. I didn't get the NSRunLoop thing. What about it?

Comment: Yes. But, my idea is alert message after data downloaded, and my device is sleeping. Not download data after alert and user interact

Comment: But you are saying that your app will resume download on its own after some interval of time since being sent to background. That isn't quite possible.

Comment: Yes, so i'm using NSRunloop. I thinks it alway run in background. Is my solution right? Now, my problem is wifi not alive in sleep mode.

Comment: No, NSRunLoop isn't going to keep the app alive in the background. You can request for some time to complete a task but that is finite. You can try masquerading as a `voip` app for periodic resumption and checking but that will in all probability get rejected.

Comment: That's mean i haven't solution for my application. ;)

Comment: Can you describe the purpose of the download? What kind of data, why it can't done when the app is in frontend?

Comment: The purpose of my application: At the daily time (Ex: 5h00 AM), i upload data to server. Every night, my application run in background, USB connected for battery charging. On time (Ex: 6h00 AM, set by application), application check new data on server and download. After data downloaded, alert message. When i get up, open device and entry application, view data. That's mean data already for my job. Because, data have big size (minimum: 200 MB) and have new data on daily.

Comment: The only way I see this happening is the app prompting user to check for content via local notification and then downloading after coming to the foreground. That sounds like bad user experience though.

Comment: Thank you any way. I think that's a solution. I'll to try for other way.